# ASP.NET: Access Session variable in global.asax

Tags: asp.net, session, global-asax

I have an ASP.NET application and in the Global.asax ' Application Error Event, I am calling a method to trace/log the error. I want to use the session variable content here. I used the below code

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //get reference to the source of the exception chain
     Exception ex = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();

     //log the details of the exception and page state to the
     //Windows 2000 Event Log
     GUI.MailClass objMail = new GUI.MailClass();
     string strError = "MESSAGE: " + ex.Message + "<br><br><br>" + "SOURCE: " + ex.Source + "<br>FORM: " + Request.Form.ToString() + "<br>QUERYSTRING: " +    Request.QueryString.ToString() + "<br>TARGETSITE: " + ex.TargetSite + "<br>STACKTRACE: " + ex.StackTrace;
     if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["trCustomerEmail"] != null)
     {
         strError = "Customer Email : " + Session["trCustomerEmail"].ToString() +"<br />"+ strError;
     }

     //Call a method to send the error details as an Email
     objMail.sendMail("test@gmail.com", "myid@gmail.com", "Error in " + Request.Form.ToString(), strError, 2);   
}
```

I am getting an error in the line of code where I am accessing the session variable. Visual Studio is telling that

> Session is not available in this context

How can I get rid of this?

Comment: Where is the error being thrown from? In aspx code beind (which event?), or in a http handler etc? This can determine if use of the session object is valid or not

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It should work if you do it like this:

```
strError = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["trCustomerEmail"]
```

Because that is what I do myself.

What exactly do you mean with: Visual Studio is telling that "Session is not available in this context"? Do you get a compiler error or a run-time exception?

You could try to be more defensive and test if there actually is a current HttpContext and a Session:

```
if (HttpContext.Current != null &&
    HttpContext.Current.Session != null) {
  strError = HttpContext.Current.Session["trCustomerEmail"]
}
```

Comment: Can you post the exception message you get when accessing the Session and the exception message that you are trying to handle?

Answer (score 3):

I think applicaiton error is specific for the whole application and a session is specific for the user. Maybe you can throw your own Exception where you save the information from the session inside your exception.

Comment: Yes. Applicationxxxx events is specific for your application, not for a session.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
HttpContext context = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context;
```

then you must use is like this:

```
context.Request.QueryString.ToString()
context.Session["key"] = "fasfaasf";
```

but if the exception was thrown before the Session object is loaded, it will be null