# Can I access the Session variable value inside the global.asax?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session, global-asax

I want to get the `session` value inside the `global.asax` files, is it possible, if yes how please ?

Comment: Please review this, may this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164503/asp-net-access-session-variable-in-global-asax

Comment: It depends: *when* do you want to access it? On Application_Start, there is no session yet.

Answer (score 2):

just try this

```
if (HttpContext.Current != null &&
    HttpContext.Current.Session != null) {
  var data= HttpContext.Current.Session["sessionvariablename"];
}
```

Also check this : [How to access session variable in global.asax file](http://forums.asp.net/t/1661936.aspx/1)